# card reading killing my battery, on macbook pro running Debian

Tags: debian, power-management, macintosh, sd-card, powertop

**I am currently using a macbook pro but the operating system is debian 8.2 not os x**

I am using a macbook pro but there's this one device that's just draining a lot of power. This USB device: Card Reader (Apple)

```
 32.5 W    100.0%                      Device         USB device: Card Reader (Apple)
  2.60 W    100.0%                      Device         Radio device: btusb
  209 mW     19.7 pkts/s                Device         Network interface: wlan0 (wl)
```

This device really drains my battery, I noticed that my laptop wouldn't even get 2 hours when not plugged in, I installed powertop. Made all the recommended changes but this device, I can't find out how to disable it. I don't even use that reader and forgot that it was there.

I configured all my devices to use limited power in my rc.local

```
echo '0' > '/proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog'
echo 'min_power' > '/sys/class/scsi_host/host0/link_power_management_policy'
echo '1' > '/sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save'
echo '1500' > '/proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-4/power/control'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-12/power/control'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-8.3/power/control'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.3/power/control'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.1/power/control'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1c.3/power/control'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1c.4/power/control'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1c.2/power/control'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1c.0/power/control'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1b.0/power/control'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:16.0/power/control'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:14.0/power/control'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:01.1/power/control'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:01.0/power/control'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:00.0/power/control'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/power/control'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:08:00.0/power/control'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:07:06.0/power/control'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:07:05.0/power/control'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:07:04.0/power/control'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:07:03.0/power/control'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:07:00.0/power/control'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:06:00.0/power/control'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:05:00.0/power/control'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:04:00.0/power/control'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:03:00.0/power/control'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.0/power/control'
```

How can I get this device to act sanely or disable it completely because I  haven't used it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [Power Management for USB, kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/power-management.txt), you will find a summary of poweroff pre-requisite settings relative to a port device:

```
echo 0 > power/pm_qos_no_power_off
echo 0 > peer/power/pm_qos_no_power_off # if it exists
echo auto > power/control # this is the default value
echo auto > <child>/power/control
echo 1 > <child>/power/persist # this is the default value
```