# disabling usb device debian

Tags: debian, usb, lsusb

How can I disable a usb device on debian? I am using a macbook pro but I have installed debian jessie 8.2 on it.

the USB device: Card Reader (Apple) is pulling way too much power and I don't even use the device.

How can I disable that device?

```
  33.8 W    100.0%                      Device         USB device: Card Reader (Apple)
  2.96 W    100.0%                      Device         Radio device: btusb
  477 mW      0.0 pkts/s                Device         Network interface: wlan0 (wl)
```

running lsusb I cannot find which device is that card reader

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05ac:8406 Apple, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 05ac:8289 Apple, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05ac:0262 Apple, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**additional information.**

dmesg | grep APPLE

```
[    0.000000] ACPI: RSDP 0x000000007AD8E014 000024 (v02 APPLE )
[    0.000000] ACPI: XSDT 0x000000007AD8E1C0 00009C (v01 APPLE  Apple00  00000000      01000013)
[    0.000000] ACPI: FACP 0x000000007AD8C000 0000F4 (v05 APPLE  Apple00  00000000 Loki 0000005F)
[    0.000000] ACPI: DSDT 0x000000007AD80000 006C1F (v03 APPLE  MacBookP 00110002 INTL 20100915)
[    0.000000] ACPI: HPET 0x000000007AD8B000 000038 (v01 APPLE  Apple00  00000001 Loki 0000005F)
[    0.000000] ACPI: APIC 0x000000007AD8A000 0000BC (v02 APPLE  Apple00  00000001 Loki 0000005F)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SBST 0x000000007AD88000 000030 (v01 APPLE  Apple00  00000001 Loki 0000005F)
[    0.000000] ACPI: ECDT 0x000000007AD87000 000053 (v01 APPLE  Apple00  00000001 Loki 0000005F)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000007AD7F000 00010B (v01 APPLE  SataAhci 00001000 INTL 20100915)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000007AD7E000 000024 (v01 APPLE  SmcDppt  00001000 INTL 20100915)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000007AD7C000 000688 (v01 APPLE  SDUsbLpt 00001000 INTL 20100915)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000007AD79000 000032 (v01 APPLE  SsdtS3   00001000 INTL 20100915)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000007AD64000 009E2C (v01 APPLE  TbtPEG11 00001000 INTL 20100915)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000007AD63000 0000B8 (v01 APPLE  Sdxc     00001000 INTL 20100915)
[    0.000000] ACPI: MCFG 0x000000007AD89000 00003C (v01 APPLE  Apple00  00000001 Loki 0000005F)
[    0.000000] ACPI: DMAR 0x000000007AD5F000 000088 (v01 APPLE  HSW      00000001 AAPL 00000001)
[    2.141500] ata1.00: ATA-8: APPLE SSD SM0512F, UXM2JA1Q, max UDMA/133
[    2.149927] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      APPLE SSD SM0512 JA1Q PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    3.051962] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     APPLE    SD Card Reader   3.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
```

sg_scan -i

```
/dev/sg0: scsi0 channel=0 id=0 lun=0 [em]
    ATA       APPLE SSD SM0512  JA1Q [rmb=0 cmdq=0 pqual=0 pdev=0x0] 
/dev/sg1: scsi1 channel=0 id=0 lun=0 [em]
    APPLE     SD Card Reader    3.00 [rmb=1 cmdq=0 pqual=0 pdev=0x0]
```

ps -ax | grep dev

```
   47 ?        S      0:00 [kdevtmpfs]
   59 ?        S<     0:00 [devfreq_wq]
  215 ?        Ss     0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
 2525 ?        Sl     0:15 /google/chrome/chrome 
 4358 pts/2    S+     0:00 grep dev
```

I've tried all the suggestions in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254030/card-reading-killing-my-battery-on-macbook-pro-running-debian) but it doesn't work. That's why I have a new question.

Comment: Where do you get the first set of outputs from? I.e. "33.8 W    100.0%".

Comment: @FaheemMitha I got the output from running powertop on my machine.

Comment: If the answers to your first question aren't good enough, you need to add more information to that question instead of opening new questions.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to credit the original answer instead of cut&copy. Maybe this will help you.

[Superuser: How do I disable my built in Card Reader in Debian?](https://superuser.com/questions/220824)

Comment: I've tried the steps in that link but they don't work for me. sg_scan and dmesg shows the device yes, but running ps ax  and looking for all the output I don't see any polling devices. These are the only things that show up when I grep for dev.    47 ?        S      0:00 [kdevtmpfs]
   59 ?        S<     0:00 [devfreq_wq]
  215 ?        Ss     0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
 2525 ?        Sl     0:10 /opt/google/chrome/chrome so I still can't find how to disable it.